# Spring Roo project failed to run with Spring 4.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo, beancreationexception

I have created a spring project with spring roo 1.2.5 and I changed the  in the pom.xml file to 4.1.1.RELEASE.

The project failed to start with the following error from the tomcat 8 server:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#bc1b9c' of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.ConversionServiceExposingInterceptor] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#bc1b9c': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'applicationConversionService' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.test.test.web.ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean] for bean with name 'applicationConversionService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.test.web.ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.test.test.web.ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean] for bean with name 'applicationConversionService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.test.web.ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:548)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4923)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5209)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#bc1b9c' of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.ConversionServiceExposingInterceptor] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#bc1b9c': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'applicationConversionService' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.test.test.web.ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean] for bean with name 'applicationConversionService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.test.web.ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:636)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1133)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1036)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:505)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:489)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1060)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:277)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.detectMappedInterceptors(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.initApplicationContext(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:196)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:120)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:76)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1560)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:540)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#bc1b9c': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'applicationConversionService' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.test.test.web.ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean] for bean with name 'applicationConversionService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.test.web.ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:636)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1133)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1036)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:505)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:276)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.test.test.web.ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean] for bean with name 'applicationConversionService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.test.web.ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:453)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.test.web.ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1320)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:246)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:395)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1346)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1317)
    ... 65 more
```

The bean has already defined in webmvc-config.xml as following:

```
<bean class="com.test.test.web.ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean" id="applicationConversionService"/>
```

Does any one has any idea on the error?

Comment: It can't find this class: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`: `com.test.test.web.ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean`

Comment: @PeterK Untill a new version of Spring Roo is developed that works with Spring 4, either stick with the Spring 3.x line or don't use Spring Roo.

Comment: @geoand: At least with 4.0.6 roo is working fine. And judged by exception that isn't issue of roo/spring.

Answer (score 0):

You changed the Spring version from 3.x to 4.x. As a *major version* change, this will cause the Roo generated class `ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean` to not be found (deprecated method could be removed, changed the way of configure some componets, etc).

So, I advice you to use the spring 3.2.11 version, which is latest of 3.X branch.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Check your deployment location ( '.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/your_project_name/WEB-INF/classes').

If it is empty (ClassNotFoundException) delete your roo project in eclipse.
Delete eclipse related files (.classpath, .settings and .project) and reimport project as maven project.